# PhoneGap 'path already exists'

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, cordova

I added acceleromter and geolocation extensions following these steps: http://www.devx.com/wireless/implement-google-maps-api-on-phonegap-using-the-device-api.html

Now when I run `phonegap install android` I get this error

```
rm: could not remove directory (code ENOTEMPTY): .../platforms/android/assets/www/plugins
rm: could not remove directory (code ENOTEMPTY): .../platforms/android/assets/www

mkdir: path already exists: .../platforms/android/assets/www
```

Is there anyway to get rid of this error? (besides undoing this setup - I still want to use google maps)